# Access Postman Examples from tests

Tags: postman, postman-mocks

I am developing a API, and have a Postman collection used with extensive tests on the endpoints. I also used Examples to be able to mock a good chunk of the API.

However, whenever something is planned to change in the response, I have to edit the tests and examples in almost the same way. In some cases, it would make sense to have the test depend directly on the example response for a part, or even the entire response.

It would make it much easier for those tests to be able to reference the example value:

```js
const expectedStatusCode = pm.examples[0].request.status; // ???

pm.test(`Status code is ${expectedStatusCode}`, () => {
    pm.response.to.have.status(expectedStatusCode)
})
```

The [Postman API](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference) reference how to access a lot of things, but there seems to be no way to either access the examples data nor read a file (so I could parse the collection JSON file, and fetch the value directy in the exported collection)

Answer (score 0):

Found the confirmation that the asked feature do not exist, and a feature request was already made to Postman on for both [accessing examples directly](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/6683) and [reading external files](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/7210)